# Understanding usage of Public DNS assigned by Amazon for an EC2 Instance and importance of Elastic IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

In my Amazon EC2 instance I have the following details. The values are just a sample:

Public DNS (IPv4) - ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com
IPv4 Public IP - 1.2.3.4
Elastic IPs - 1.2.3.4

I understand that when you have an elastic IP, then every time your instance gets rebooted, you will receive the public IP same as the elastic IP. But the thing is, I am given a public DNS here. So, my question is

1. If I have given a public DNS then why do I need an Elastic IP?
2. Does the public DNS change together with the public IP if I don't have an Elastic IP?
3. If the public DNS changes, then what is the use of it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public DNS name associated to the public IPv4 address is in the form: `ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com` where *1.2.3.4* is the IP address associated to the instance *while it is up and running* ! Meaning that when your instance is shut down and restarted (not rebooted), you *will* get a new public IPv4 address with a new DNS name.
Considering the latter:

1. because you can't predict the DNS name you will get
2. indeed
3. just convenient, also it might be interesting to use it as a *CNAME* target if you were to create a dynamic DNS system that would register with *Route53*

Answer (score 1):

Just going to share why if you are serious you really do need am ElasticIP. No matter what your DNS is.

In cases where one is creating a system which relies on specific end users sending data into and receiving data from the server. If you need to scale the server which is facing the world, (not even talking about those behind the Gateway), then suddenly when you scale and it took you all of 10 minutes you will find yourself with a lot of irate people who suddenly cannot get into the servers due to the fact that the IP address they have is no longer valid.

This is what ElasticIP is made for. Never have to worry about the IP.

There are many other Scenarios which can be laid out I think ElasticIP is more than just convenience. It is essential for any serious system. 
MHO